# Recurring cracked window

Tags: windows, cracks

We had new windows fitted in June 2019 and have since had to have a small side window repaired due to it cracking.

It has happened for a second time now and we are worrying that its a bigger problem, maybe with the house itself.

Has anyone any experience with windows that keep cracking or know what could be the reason for it? [image][image][image][image][image][image][image]

Comment: Can you attach a picture of the crack and the full window?

Comment: House/foundation could be shifting, or that's the window exposed to projectiles (balls, rocks, etc) from (neighbors, street, etc.)

Comment: @Ecnerwal - windows usually have a lot of give.   I would question if it is cracking on how it is installed.   In theory it could crack based on movement if it was installed in a space where it had no "gaps".   If you give a window 1/8-1/4" on each side and shim it, then the structural movement should be breaking a ton of other stuff if the window is effected.

Comment: If you have a picture of the -cracked- window that would be helpful. Any doors nearby? If so, any changes there? Notice anything at the foundation? Picture of the side of the house including the window?

Comment: Sure sounds like the window & frame were installed either too tightly or in a non-square frame, causing a lot of stress on the glass.

Comment: Thank you all for replys. I will attach some pictures. There is a door on the same side that is not closing properly, but only when its a hot day.

Comment: I have uploaded some pictures to the original post. There are a couple of cracks on the outside of the house. In one of the pictures you can see one to the bottom left and to the left of the window. I have also included a picture of the door that sticks. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

OK - Either this is a huge optical illusion or my eyes tell me that the window looks like it is being squeezed at the bottom.

It is simple - windows should never crack like this unless something hits it or it goes through a major earthquake.   Let's remove the issues with your house.   It looks like there is movement and it looks like this may be seasonal/temp related.   This is completely out of scope for the window issue.   You may have a huge foundation issue, maybe it is no big deal - doesn't matter.

You need a new window.  It needs to be sized correctly.   There should be space on at least one of the sides and either top or bottom.   Windows are not packed into an opening.   They are put into an opening and screwed into place using shims.   This is to give the window the ability to move and to get a more plumb install.

The other option that you have it is use the same window but shave off room on the outside - I do not recommend this though because it could decrease the integrity of the unit which seems to already have issues.   But if you keep putting glass panes in there they will certainly keep breaking.

Comment: @Ecnerwal- the crack is on the inside so have ruled out anything hitting it from the outside.

Comment: Thanks for your response @DMoore . Now I have more of an insight, I will insist the installers size the window correctly and not let them fob me off with just replacing the glass again.

Comment: @S.L.W - I am really curious from your pictures if you have even measure the very top width and the bottom width of the window/opening.   It sure seems to me that the bottom is squeezed and may have twisted slightly due to this.

Comment: Might consider having them not only replace tha pane with the proper shape, but use lucite/plexiglass instead of glass. Plastic is far less prone to shattering under strain.

Comment: @WayfaringStranger - might be a good idea but if he is having them installed it should have a warranty period - they may need to take old window out to measure correctly.  It depends on the framing and trim.

Comment: Just measured top and bottom, coming up with around 18.5" on both. Would even a few mm difference cause this?